# Sharing a Pane between different Scenes javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to implement a series of menu buttons that would switch between different scenes, however, I am trying to optimize it in a way where I can reuse my menu pane (where all the menu buttons are) for all scenes that would display it.

Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene scene1, scene2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Arty's Drone Delivery Server");

    //MainMenu pane
    final VBox vpane = new VBox(10);
    final Button postB = new Button("Postcodes");
    final Button dronesB = new Button("Drones");
    final Button staffB = new Button("Staff");
    vpane.getChildren().addAll(postB, dronesB, staffB);

    //Drones Box
    DronesBox dronesPane = new DronesBox();
    //Poscodes Box
    PostCodeBox postCodesPane = new PostCodeBox();

    //Layout 2
    BorderPane border2 = new BorderPane();
    border2.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    border2.setLeft(vpane);
    border2.setCenter(dronesPane);
    scene2 = new Scene(border2, 600, 400);

    //Layout 1
    BorderPane border1 = new BorderPane();
    border1.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    border1.setLeft(vpane);
    border1.setCenter(postCodesPane);
    scene1 = new Scene(border1, 600, 400);

    //button event listeners
    postB.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene1));
    dronesB.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene2));

    window.setScene(scene1);
    window.show();
    }


}

class PostCodeBox extends VBox{
    PostCodeBox(){
        Label title = new Label("Postcodes:");
        TextField textbox = new TextField();
        textbox.setPrefSize(200, 350);
        textbox.setEditable(false);
        textbox.appendText("SO16 3UH \n");
        textbox.appendText("SO14 3WL \n");

        HBox actionPane = new HBox(3);
        Button add = new Button("Add");
        Button remove = new Button("Remove");
        Button edit = new Button("Edit");
        actionPane.getChildren().addAll(add, remove, edit);

        this.getChildren().addAll(textbox, actionPane);

    }
}
```

DronesBox is done with the same principle like PostCodeBox.

Now, from what I understand, when Drones button is pressed, it hops on to the next scene, but it has problems carrying over the vpane, which technically was added to both. It looks to me that I somehow have to make it a "master pane" that would display on all button press variations.

[image: Scene 1]

[image: Scene 2]

Another way I could try to do this is by removing an object from a borderpane and adding a new one, but then I am not switching scenes at all.

Comment: A node can appear at most once in the entire scene graph (i.e. it can only have one parent/scene). In my opinion, you should forgo multiple scenes and simply modify the one scene to display the different views. This can be done by modifying a layout's (e.g. `BorderPane`) children or by changing the visibility of the different views.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw that solved the issue. When should I think about switching scenes then, if not in this kind of scenario.

Comment: I would say if the different UIs have nothing to do with each other (other than one can "change into" another). For instance, a login page and the UI that said page "guards". Basically, if it's possible to have the different UIs in different windows, but you want to use the same window, then switch scenes (though even then, technically you could simply switch the root of the scene). Since in your case you have a "static" menu that just changes part of the UI, using the same scene makes sense.